# What do I return for an Angular binded property while waiting for $onInit callbacks to complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular service like:

```
appModule.factory('dataService', DataService);

DataService.$inject = ['dataContext'];

function DataService(dataContext) {
    var service = Object.create(DataService.prototype);
    service._dataContext = dataContext;
    service._details = {};
    service.$onInit();

    return service;
}

DataService.prototype = {
    $onInit: function () {
        this._dataContext.combinedQuery(DataQuery)
            .then(function (data) {
                this._details = data[0];
            }.bind(this));
    },

    Details: function () {
        return this._details;
    }    
};
```

The Controller consuming it is like:

```
DetailsController.$inject = ["dataService"];

function DetailsController(dataService) {
    this._dataService = dataService;
}

DetailsController.prototype = {
    $onInit: function () {
        this.details = this._dataService.Details;
    },

}
```

And the View is binding `{{$DetailsController.details}}`.

When running `DataService.$onInit` will return, the `DataService.Details` function return value will be bound to `DetailsController.details` before `this._details = data[0]` has been called.

What should I be returning from `DataService.Details` so that once `this._details` is set, the data is shown on the bound view?

I think it should be something like below, but I don't want to call `$onInit` again:

```
return this.$onInit()
        .then(function () {
            return this._details;
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: If you try to log `data` on the `.then( function ( data ))` what do you get? And, essentially, you would like to execute `Details : function()` after the latter step?

Comment: I do get the correct value in `.then(function (data)`, but `Details : function()` is called before it. So yes, I'd like to execute it after the `.then`.

Comment: I've found one solution not sure if it is best. I assigned the promise to a variable like this `this.init = this._dataContext.combinedQuery(DataQuery)`. and in `Details: function()` return `this.init.then(func....`

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `Promises`

```
appModule.factory('dataService', DataService);

DataService.$inject = ['dataContext'];

function DataService(dataContext) {
    DataService.prototype().then( function (err, prototype){
      if(err){
       return err;
      }
       //Else
       var service = Object.create(prototype);
       service._dataContext = dataContext;
       service._details = {};
       service.$onInit();
       if(service){
         return service;
       }
    });
}

DataService.prototype = {
  return new Promise( function( resolve, reject){
    $onInit: function () {
        this._dataContext.combinedQuery(DataQuery)
            .then(function (data) {
                this._details = data[0];
            }.bind(this));
    }

    if( this.details ){
      Details: function () {
        return resolve( this._details );
      }   
    } else {
        return reject({err: 'Unable to set details'})
    }

  });  
};
```

I can't guarantee if the code above works 100% since I did not build a `Plunker` or similar but, it really seems like it's an `asynchronous` issue. If this does not work the, you should wrap `$on.init()` into a `Promise` also.

Anyways, I never seen writing `services/factories` like you do, so I'm a bit confused about it.

Hope it helps a bit anyways.

Comment: Thanks, I think I essentially do that in my comment above where I assign the promise to a variable `this.init`, although this looks more explicit.

Comment: Uhm, well, it depens, I always explicit it like that so I can chain easily different `async tasks` all together. If you manage to make it almost work let me know so I can help you and fix my answer also.